# QueryDataProvider for children components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I need to create a provider in react + typescript, which takes queryData from useQuery (React-Query) as a parameter. I would like it to provide all children with information about data and the ability to refetch data. In addition, after passing queryData, I would like it to return loading/error/success component depending on the status of useQuery.

```
export function DasboardView(props) {
  const queryData = useGetDasboardInfo();
  return (
    <Query {...queryData}>
      <QuerySucccess>
        <DasboardComponent/>
      </QuerySucccess>
      <QueryError/>
    </Query>
  );
}
```

In `<DasboardComponent/>` I would like to have info about Data from queryData

Comment: Hello, can you provide information about the specific problem you are facing? This doesn't quite seems to be a question

Comment: If you are using a custom hook, you can easily do that with `react-query` unless you have multiple children that need the same data, which will use Context API instead. However, I failed to see your precise requirements according to the info you have provided. Please add some more color to your need so we can provide further help.

Comment: pretty much this: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-and-react-context